# Active directory failing to deploy a converted MSI file to clients via GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016, msi, agent

I have been struggling with deploying a Kaspersky network agent to my clients that are part of the work Domain.

I have performed the below steps;

1. Joined the client to the domain
2. Ping the name of the domain as well as my AD which is responsible for
   the deployment of the software
3. Tested if the MSI file works on a separate machine(mind due, the MSI was a .exe which I converted to MSI using third party software)

These are the errors I get from my event viewer..

1. **Software Installation:** Software Installation encountered an unexpected error while reading from the MSI file "name_of_msi".msi.  The error was not serious enough to justify halting the operation.  The following error was encountered: The operation completed successfully.
2. **klnagent:** Failed to retrieve the updates: distribution points are unavailable, connection to the server is denied.
3. **NETLOGON:** The session setup from the computer KAS-CLIENT2 failed to authenticate. The following error occurred:
   Access is denied.
4. **OSConfigAgent:** 2023-04-08T17:03:56.9940Z OSConfigAgent Warning: Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = The service is currently unavailable.
5. **Schannel**: An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request has failed.

I think these above are all the warnings and errors relating to the issue I am facing, I suspect it has to do something with a certain connection to the client that keeps on denying access. Please help.

Comment: Is the application installed? Yes/No.

Comment: No it has not been installed.

Comment: The errors do not (all) look associated with the MSI installer. Especially the "netlogon" errors ...

Comment: The thing is i am able to deploy other applications but when i comes to the kaspersky agent software it gives me those errors.